# Plotting two vectors on the unit circle

Tags: plotting, graphics

I would like to plot a vector on the unit circle, depending on an angle `Pi/k`, and the same vector rotated by an angle `d`. I try the following:

```
k = 0.9; d = 0.3;
pt = {Sin[Pi/k], Cos[Pi/k]};
pt2 = {pt[[1]]*Cos[d] + pt[[2]]*Sin[d], 
pt[[2]]*Cos[d] - pt[[1]]*Sin[d]};

Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, pt, {0, 0}, pt2}], Axes -> True, 
AxesLabel -> {x, z}, PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}]
```

In some cases, like when `k=0.9` and `d=0.3` as above, this almost works, except that the first vector has no arrowhead, only a line (see figure). In other cases, as when `k=1`, Only the second vector is drawn. Can anyone see what the problem is?

[image: The plotted vectors]

Comment: You have small mistake with the order of the points. Try this! `Graphics[{{Dashed, Circle[]},
  Arrow /@ {{{0, 0}, pt}, {{0, 0}, pt2}}},
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, z}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}]`

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[k_, d_] := Graphics[{Circle[], #, Dashed, Rotate[#, d, {0, 0}]} &@ 
                                                            Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Sin[Pi/k], Cos[Pi/k]}}]]

f[.9, .3]
```

[image]

---

```
f[k_, d_, c_] := Graphics[{Circle[], Thick, c, #, Dashed, Rotate[#, d, {0, 0}]} &@
                         Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Sin[k 2 Pi/11], Cos[k 2 Pi/11]}}]]
Export["c:\\test.gif", 
       Flatten@Table[(SeedRandom@k;c = RGBColor[Sequence @@ RandomReal[1, {3}]]; 
                     f[k, d, c]), {k, 1, 11}, {d, 2 Pi, 0, -Pi/12}], 
      "DisplayDurations" -> .2]
```

[image]